# Word for: sideways descent down a steep slope?

Tags: single-word-requests

When descending a steep slope composed of dirt, gravel or slippery stone, one may at some point transition from a forward walk to a slower, more careful sideways one, using (say) the outside edge of the left foot and and inside edge of the right foot to dig into the ground and provide better purchase while descending.

Is there a word for this mode of locomotion, or one which could be considered to best describe it?

Usage ex:
"He _____ down the slope, picking his way around crags and boulders."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is possible to use "**sidle down**" [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sidled)

> **sidle** 1. to move sideways or obliquely.

And from snippet views in Google Books:

> **Being There: The Parables of Jesus in a Different Voice** O'Malley, William J. · 2016. *He hauled the mule's reins over her head and sidled down the rockfall through the bushes.*

> **The Forgetting Tide** Mike Hoinville · 2015 *... with a kind of side stepping motion as if he had skis on, he sidled down the very steep slope*

> **People of the Bear Mother** T. D. Austin · 2012 *Then to my horror, as he sidled down the sloping boulder, the Grandfather slipped on a muddy patch of clay,*

(NB The approved way of descending loose ground, e.g. scree, is to go down forwards - this lessens the chances of falling and of broken ankles.)

Answer (score 2):

In skiing, the term is:

> [**Side-slipping**](https://psia-c.org/sideslip-fall-line/)

I imagine it could be used in other circumstances.

The analogous term for *ascending* a ski slope is:

> **Side-stepping**

which actually better describes a pedestrian ascent.

Comment: *Side-stepping* is also used in both climbing and trekking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a verb, but a noun for paths that go sideways down a steep slope in mountainous terrain is switch-back:

From: [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/switchback):
A zigzag road, trail, or section of railroad tracks for climbing a steep hill